# Converting string column to dummy variables with duplicate keys

Tags: r, sparse-matrix, dummy-variable

I am trying to convert this -

```
> df.orig <- data.frame(id = c('foo', 'bar', 'foo'), action = c('abc','def','ghi'))
> df.orig
   id action
1 foo    abc
2 bar    def
3 foo    ghi
```

Into:

```
> df.new <- data.frame(id = c('foo', 'bar'), action_abc = c(1,0), action_def = c(0,1), action_ghi = c(1,0))
> df.new
   id action_abc action_def action_ghi
1 foo          1          0          1
2 bar          0          1          0
```

`sparse.model.matrix` and `dcast` seem to not handle multiple keys ('`foo`') very well.

```
> sparse.model.matrix(id ~ action - 1, df.orig)
3 x 3 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
  actionabc actiondef actionghi
1         1         .         .
2         .         1         .
3         .         .         1
```

Comment: `dcast` seems to work fine: `reshape2::dcast(df.orig, id ~ action, fun.agg = length)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `table`

```
  df <- data.frame(id = c('foo', 'bar', 'foo'), action = c('abc','def','ghi'),stringsAsFactors = F)

  table(df$id,df$action)

      abc def ghi
  bar   0   1   0
  foo   1   0   1
```